# Render Flutter animation directly to video

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

Considering that Flutter uses its own graphics engine, is there a way to render Flutter animations directly to video, or create screenshots in a frame by frame fashion?

One use case would be that this allows easier demonstration for the audience.

For example, an author wants to create a Flutter animation tutorial, where they builds a demo app and writes a companion blog post, using the animation GIF/videos rendered directly with Flutter.

Another example would be one developer outside the UI team discovers a complex animation has tiny mistake in it. Without actually learning the animation code, they can render the animation into a video and edit that short clip with annotations, then send it to the UI team for diagnoses.

Comment: for the second case, this could be helpful: [timeDilation](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/scheduler/timeDilation.html), more [here](https://flutter.io/debugging/#debugging-animations)

Comment: Why not just record a video from the emulator, or even the real device?

Comment: @John did you find a solution?

Answer (score 15):

It's not pretty, but I have managed to get a prototype working.
Firstly, all animations need to be powered by a single main animation controller so that we can step through to any part of the animation we want. Secondly, the widget tree that we want to record has to be wrapped inside a `RepaintBoundary` with a global key. The RepaintBoundary and it's key can produce snapshots of the widget tree as such:

```dart
Future<Uint8List> _capturePngToUint8List() async {
    // renderBoxKey is the global key of my RepaintBoundary
    RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = renderBoxKey.currentContext.findRenderObject(); 
    
    // pixelratio allows you to render it at a higher resolution than the actual widget in the application.
    ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: 2.0);
    ByteData byteData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
    Uint8List pngBytes = byteData.buffer.asUint8List();

    return pngBytes;
  }
```

The above method can then be used inside a loop which captures the widget tree into pngBytes, and steps the animationController forward by a deltaT specified by the framerate you want as such:

```
double t = 0;
int i = 1;

setState(() {
  animationController.value = 0.0;
});

Map<int, Uint8List> frames = {};
double dt = (1 / 60) / animationController.duration.inSeconds.toDouble();

while (t <= 1.0) {
  print("Rendering... ${t * 100}%");
  var bytes = await _capturePngToUint8List();
  frames[i] = bytes;

  t += dt;
  setState(() {
    animationController.value = t;
  });
  i++;
}
```

Finally, all these png frames can be piped into an ffmpeg subprocess to be written into a video.
I haven't managed to get this part working nicely yet (*UPDATE*: Scroll down to see solution to this), so what I've done instead is write out all the png-frames into actual png files and I then manually run ffmpeg inside the folder where they are written. (Note: I've used flutter desktop to be able to access my installation of ffmpeg, but there is [a package on pub.dev to get ffmpeg on mobile too](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg))

```dart
List<Future<File>> fileWriterFutures = [];

frames.forEach((key, value) {
  fileWriterFutures.add(_writeFile(bytes: value, location: r"D:\path\to\my\images\folder\" + "frame_$key.png"));
});

await Future.wait(fileWriterFutures);

_runFFmpeg();
```

Here is my file-writer help-function:

```
Future<File> _writeFile({@required String location, @required Uint8List bytes}) async {
  File file = File(location);
  return file.writeAsBytes(bytes);
}
```

And here is my FFmpeg runner function:

```dart
void _runFFmpeg() async {
  // ffmpeg -y -r 60 -start_number 1 -i frame_%d.png -c:v libx264 -preset medium -tune animation -pix_fmt yuv420p test.mp4
  var process = await Process.start(
      "ffmpeg",
      [
        "-y", // replace output file if it already exists
        "-r", "60", // framrate
        "-start_number", "1",
        "-i", r"./test/frame_%d.png", // <- Change to location of images
        "-an", // don't expect audio
        "-c:v", "libx264rgb", // H.264 encoding
        "-preset", "medium",
        "-crf",
        "10", // Ranges 0-51 indicates lossless compression to worst compression. Sane options are 0-30
        "-tune", "animation",
        "-preset", "medium",
        "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p",
        r"./test/test.mp4" // <- Change to location of output
      ],
      mode: ProcessStartMode.inheritStdio // This mode causes some issues at times, so just remove it if it doesn't work. I use it mostly to debug the ffmpeg process' output
   );

  print("Done Rendering");
}
```

## Update:

Since this answer was posted I have figured out how to pipe the images directly to ffmpeg without the need of first writing out all the files. The following is my updated render function taken from one of my widgets. Some variables are present within the widget's context, but I hope that their values can be inferred from the context:

```dart
void render([double? pixelRatio]) async {
    // If already rendering, return
    if (isRendering) return;

    String outputFileLocation = "final.mp4";

    setState(() {
      isRendering = true;
    });

    timeline.stop();

    await timeline.animateTo(0.0, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 700), curve: Curves.easeInOutQuad);
    setState(() {
      timeline.value = 0.0;
    });

    await Future.delayed(const Duration(milliseconds: 100));

    try {
      int width = canvasSize.width.toInt();
      int height = canvasSize.height.toInt();
      int frameRate = 60;
      int numberOfFrames = frameRate * (timeline.duration!.inSeconds);

      print("starting ffmpeg..");
      var process = await Process.start(
          "ffmpeg",
          [
            "-y", // replace output file if it already exists
            // "-f", "rawvideo",
            // "-pix_fmt", "rgba",
            "-s", "${width}x$height", // size
            "-r", "$frameRate", // framrate
            "-i", "-",
            "-frames", "$numberOfFrames",
            "-an", // don't expect audio
            "-c:v", "libx264rgb", // H.264 encoding
            "-preset", "medium",
            "-crf",
            "10", // Ranges 0-51 indicates lossless compression to worst compression. Sane options are 0-30
            "-tune", "animation",
            "-preset", "medium",
            "-pix_fmt", "yuv420p",
            "-vf",
            "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2", // ensure width and height is divisible by 2
            outputFileLocation
          ],
          mode: ProcessStartMode.detachedWithStdio,
          runInShell: true);

      print("writing to ffmpeg...");
      RenderRepaintBoundary boundary = paintKey.currentContext!.findRenderObject()! as RenderRepaintBoundary;

      pixelRatio = pixelRatio ?? 1.0;
      print("Pixel Ratio: $pixelRatio");

      for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfFrames; i++) {
        Timeline.startSync("Render Video Frame");
        double t = (i.toDouble() / numberOfFrames.toDouble());
        // await timeline.animateTo(t, duration: Duration.zero);
        timeline.value = t;

        ui.Image image = await boundary.toImage(pixelRatio: pixelRatio);
        ByteData? rawData = await image.toByteData(format: ui.ImageByteFormat.png);
        var rawIntList = rawData!.buffer.asInt8List().toList();
        Timeline.finishSync();

        if (i % frameRate == 0) {
          print("${((t * 100.0) * 100).round() / 100}%");
        }

        process.stdin.add(rawIntList);

        image.dispose();
      }
      await process.stdin.flush();

      print("stopping ffmpeg...");
      await process.stdin.close();
      process.kill();
      print("done!");
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    } finally {
      await timeline.animateTo(beforeValue, duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.easeInOutQuad);
      setState(() {
        isRendering = false;
      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: Can I have info, how `fileWriterFutures` has been defined?

Comment: @PurvikRana It's just a list of `Future<File>`, `List<Future<File>> fileWriterFutures = [];`. I think `List<Future<void>> fileWriterFutures = [];` works as well.

Comment: Ok. Let me try with this.

Comment: Since 2020 has there been any library to make this job easier/safer? PS you are a wizard man!

Comment: @AdrianMoisa Thanks xD I have not seen any sadly. I added an update to the answer with my new method that can create renders without the need for writing out all the intermediary files. Hope it helps.

Comment: @ErikW.Gren Are you available to collaborate on a pub.dev plugin for this function? As this seems to be a topic quite a few people are interested in, I am sure this would be enormously helpful for the flutter Community...

Comment: Are there alternatives to ffmpeg? so that we can render videos in the app so it doesn't depend on ffmpeg exec

Comment: How about audio? in frame or specific duration time

Comment: @AdrianMoisa Yes, i have just release a package for that. Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75251733/11003497)

Answer (score 2):

I used Erik's answer as a starting point for my own implementation and would like to add to his original answer.

After saving all the png images to the target location, I used the ffmpeg package for Flutter to create a video of all the images. Since it took a while to find the right settings to create a video that could also be played by QuickTime Player, I want to share them with you:

```
final FlutterFFmpeg _flutterFFmpeg =
    new FlutterFFmpeg(); // Create new ffmpeg instance somewhere in your code

// Function to create the video. All png files must be available in your target location prior to calling this function.
Future<String> _createVideoFromPngFiles(String location, int framerate) async {
  final dateAsString = DateFormat('ddMMyyyy_hhmmss').format(DateTime.now());
  final filePath =
      "$location/video_$dateAsString.mov"; // had to use mov to be able to play the video on QuickTime

  var arguments = [
    "-y", // Replace output file if it already exists
    "-r", "$framerate", // Your target framerate
    "-start_number", "1",
    "-i",
    "$location/frame_%d.png", // The location where you saved all your png files
    "-an", // Don't expect audio
    "-c:v",
    "libx264", // H.264 encoding, make sure to use the full-gpl ffmpeg package version
    "-preset", "medium",
    "-crf",
    "10", // Ranges 0-51 indicates lossless compression to worst compression. Sane options are 0-30
    "-tune", "animation",
    "-preset", "medium",
    "-pix_fmt",
    "yuv420p", // Set the pixel format to make it compatible for QuickTime
    "-vf",
    "pad=ceil(iw/2)*2:ceil(ih/2)*2", // Make sure that height and width are divisible by 2
    filePath
  ];

  final result = await _flutterFFmpeg.executeWithArguments(arguments);
  return result == 0
      ? filePath
      : ''; // Result == 0 indicates that video creation was successful
}
```

If you are using `libx264`, make sure that you follow the instructions for the [flutter_ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg) package: You must use the `full-gpl` version, which includes the x264 library.

Depending on the length of your animation, the desired framerate, the pixel ratio and the device's memory, saving all frames before writing the files could cause memory issues. Therefore, depending on your use case, you may want to pause/resume your animation and write the files in multiple batches so that you don't risk exceeding the available memory.

Answer (score 2):

## Render Package (Jan. 2023)

I have now developed a high-level [render package](https://pub.dev/packages/render) that takes @Erik W.'s approach and optimizes the repaint boundary capturing (image writing & converting process) and made it easier to use the functionality of related ffmpeg functions.

Wrap your widget with `Render`widget:

```dart
import 'package:render/render.dart';

final controller = RenderController();

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Render(
      controller: controller,
      child: Container(),
   );
}
```

And then capture the motion with the controller:

```dart
final result = await renderController.captureMotion(
     duration,
     format: Format.gif,
);

final file = result.output;
```

Comment: Cool! In what way would you say that you've "heavily optimized" the approach? While it looks easier to use, I see that you still write out all the images to a temporary directory instead of piping them to ffmpeg directly (see my update), and it's also not rendering in parallel which could potentially be possible using perhaps the upcoming multi-window support. Does your library perform measurable faster?

Comment: Also, when you write "Update 2023" it looks a bit like I wrote this post so maybe change that title..

Comment: @ErikW.Gren The optimization is described in the documentation, but in short flutter has the option to convert UI images to png(used in screen recorder), which takes up to 200ms longer than converting a raw with ffmpeg. This makes a significant difference when calculating dozens of images. I haven't changed too much in your ffmpeg code;

Piping: As far as i know piping on Android/Ios is not possible with fffmpegKit, `Process.start()` is only supported on Desktop, not on mobile. But you seem to have more insights here, maybe check it out;

Thanks for the criticism. Updated the title.