# Encode Flutter animation scene as video file

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

I'm writing an app that allows to make art presentations based on bunch of Flutter's animations. Finally, when user complete work, a result animations should be exported as video file.

I think about a Dummy Render Engine, to be able to make video in background...

**My question is**: what is right way to implement Video Render Engine for Flutter?

I'm trying to learn Flutter's [rendering library](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/rendering-library.html) but it is not clear for me, what is start point to create custom render engine.

Also I found a similar question without answer [Render Flutter animation directly to video](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52274511/render-flutter-animation-directly-to-video)